# Copy database from one azure subscription to another subscription

Tags: azure-sql-database

I am trying to copy a database from production to development environment. Both the servers are in Azure, I have made the credentials same in both the server, but I am getting below while executing in SSMS.

Msg 45134, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
The remote partner server name 'XXXXXXXXXX.database.windows.net.database.windows.net' could not be resolved.

I am executing the script from master database in target database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying a database to a different subscription has worked for me using the following procedure:

(1) Create a new Azure SQL Server on a different resource group.

```
New-AzureSqlDatabaseServer -Location "East US" -AdministratorLogin "AdminLogin"  -AdministratorLoginPassword "AdminPassword"
```

(2) Copy the source database to the newly created Azure SQL Server.

```
Start-AzureSqlDatabaseCopy -ServerName "SourceServer" -DatabaseName "Orders" -PartnerServer "NewlyCreatedServer" -PartnerDatabase "OrdersCopy"
```

(3) Move the resource group of the Newly created Azure SQL Server to another subscription.

```
Move-AzureRmResource -DestinationResourceGroupName [-DestinationSubscriptionId ] -ResourceId [-Force] [-ApiVersion ] [-Pre] [-DefaultProfile ] [-InformationAction ] [-InformationVariable ] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm] []
```

Comment: Is this powershell script?

Comment: Yes, it is PowerShell.

Comment: Cant we do it in SSMS?

Comment: To my knowledge there is no way to move a resource group using Transact-SQL on SSMS. T-SQL does not have a statement for that.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to copy an Azure SQL Database using T-SQL as [described in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-copy?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-powershell#copy-to-a-different-server) but it requires you to use the short server name. E.g:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE [Database1] AS COPY OF [server1].[Database1]
```

If you used the full server name, like in:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE [Database1] AS COPY OF [server1.database.windows.net].[Database1]
```

you will see the error you encountered.